# Why is the post title and content automatically being displayed in the post thumbnail (Featured image)?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I use the following code to show the post thumbnail (only):

```
    <?php // Create and run custom loop
        $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
        $custom_posts->query('post_type=page_content&sections=ThemeCL');
        while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="float-left">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But for some reason the title and content of the post is being shown (inside

tags!):

```
        <div class="block-2 border-top">
        <h2><a href="http://localhost/wpac/?blocks=mainbar-2" title="Permalink to Mainbar" rel="bookmark">Mainbar</a></h2>

                    <div class="float-left">

                <a href="http://localhost/wpac/?blocks=mainbar" title="Permalink to Mainbar Left" rel="bookmark"><img width="160" height="150" src="http://localhost/wpac/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/showcase2.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="showcase2" title="showcase2" /></a>
                <p><p>Hello this is the title Hello this is the post content</p>
</p>
            </div>
```

I only want the post thumbnail (Featured Image) to be shown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail()` should not do this on its own. Do you have extra plugins enabled that could hook into it and add this stuff?

Comment: try using `the_title()` fn instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
<?php
//Get the Thumbnail URL
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 720,405 ), false, '' );
echo $src[0];
?>
```